# Why fluentd grep exlude filter doesn't work?

Tags: ruby, filter, fluentd

Why isn't this filtering?

```
<source>
  @type dummy
  tag kubernetes.log
  dummy [{"log":"1234", "stream":"stdout", "kubernetes":{"container_name":"log-collector-fluentd" }, "time":"2017-05-04T15:01:21.000000000Z"}]
</source>

<filter kubernetes.**>
   @type grep
   exclude1 kubernetes.container_name log-collector-fluentd
</filter>

<match kubernetes.**>
  @type             stdout
</match>
```

Testing:

```
$ /opt/td-agent/embedded/bin/ruby -- /usr/sbin/td-agent -c /fluentd.conf
2017-05-05 06:22:58 +0000 kubernetes.log: {"log":"1234","stream":"stdout","kubernetes":{"container_name":"log-collector-fluentd"},"time":"2017-05-04T15:01:21.000000000Z"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the fluentd grep filter does not currently support nested value.

This is known issue. See:
https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/issues/902

Comment: grep does support nested search now .. see https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/issues/1578